# How to access a function not part of component in unit testing in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-template

I want to test a function that returns true/false but is not the part of the component in unit test case. How do I get the reference of it in my spec file?

Dummy component :

```
function Validate(abc){

}

@Directive({
    selector: [abc-credit]
})

export class CreditDirective {
    this.valid=Validate(abc);
}
```

Spec file:

```
import {CreditDirective} from './credit.directive';

describe('CreditDirective', () => {
    let component: TestLayoutComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestLayoutComponent>;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [CreditDirective, TestLayoutComponent],
            imports: [FormsModule, UtilitiesModule, BrowserAnimationsModule]
        })
            .compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestLayoutComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });

    }));

   it('should properly execute Validate()', function (){
        expect(validate(cardType)).toBeTruthy();
   });

});

@Component({
    selector: 'test-layout',
    template: 'some template'
})

export class TestLayoutComponent {
}
```

Validate() is not a part of either TestLayoutComponent or CardDirective. So how do I access it in the test case?

Comment: You need to also export your Validate function with `export function Validate(abc){ ` and then you can import it in your tests with `import {CreditDirective, Validate} from './credit.directive';`

Comment: @nemesv It worked, Thank you :)
If you could add a comment with your answer so that I can mark it as approved :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dedicated spec file and import the function, so that you can test that function in isolation, of course you need to export the function

Comment: It worked by just exporting the function. Thank you :)